# ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_8" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 6557, 40), found shape=(None, 40)

Tags: python, audio, input, deep-learning, lstm

I'm working with audio data, extracting features, storing it in a CSV file, and loading data from the CSV file. Getting the above error please help me to solve it! I've made all the attempts I knew. I'm pretty lost here! My code is added below: I'm getting this error for fit() function.

```
def build_model(input_shape): 

# build network topology
model = keras.Sequential()

# 2 LSTM layers
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape= input_shape, return_sequences=True)) #added flatten new
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64)) #return_sequences=True)

# dense layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

# output layer
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

return model
```

Creating network:

```
 # create network
input_shape = (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1]) 
model = build_model(input_shape) 
# compile model
optimiser = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimiser,
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# train model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_validation, y_validation), batch_size=32, epochs=30)

# plot accuracy/error for training and validation
plot_history(history)

# evaluate model on test set
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

[1. Model Summary screenshot for the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjFJY.png)
 [2. Error Message screenshot for that model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7aJx.png)

Solution: [Solution for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48313578/19383696)

Comment: well it is expecting a shape (n,6557,40) but getting shape (m,40), have you checked the shapes of x_train and validation? reshape them? otherwise change the architecture so that shapes that it expects are right. use model.summary() to get the appropriate shape of the layers

Comment: what if setting the input_shape = 1 ? or to X_train.shape[0] only

Comment: @Ehsan  not working

Comment: @Ritwick Jha, I reshaped and got this error: "Input 0 of layer "lstm_14" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 6557, 40, 1)"
Can you suggest to me what kind of change in architecture you are suggesting?

Comment: can you show the modal summary so i can see what shapes are expected at each layer? you can do that yourself and figure out where the shapes are going wrong.

Comment: @RitwickJha I have added the model summary and error message screenshot in the problem description!